# Custom .woff format fonts in Sendgrid - how to use?

Tags: html, css, sendgrid

I am trying to figure out how to use custom fonts in Sendgrid. Google fonts work properly, but custom .woff format font doesn´t seem to work. I have tried 3 solutions below. When I use solution nr. 1 in Preview tab it gets applied, but in the email it´s not

Would appreciate any suggestions on the problem.

1.

```html
<head><link href="https://somelink" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><style> 
* { font-family: 'BrownLight', sans-serif; } 
</style></head>
```

2.

```html
<head>
<style>
@media screen {
    font-family: 'BrownLight';
    src: url('somelink.woff') format('woff');
}
.text {
    font-family: 'BrownLight';
}
</style>
</head>
```

3.

```html
<head>
 <style>
    @media screen {
        @import url('https://somelink');
    }
    * { font-family: 'BrownLight', sans-serif; } 

 </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I assume you have a URL where the WOFF font file itself is hosted. You can then follow what a Google Font would do, like [this example](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap).

```css
<head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'BrownLight';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-display: swap;
      src: url(YOUR_FONT_URL) format('woff');
    }

    .text {
      font-family: 'BrownLight', sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Though, do note that many clients do not support web fonts. You can see more on [adding custom fonts in the SendGrid documentation here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/editor#adding-custom-fonts-using-the-html-head).

Comment: Thank you @philnash. Yes, that is what I realised that many email clients do not support web fonts. But I got it to work on Apple Mail and iPhone.